# Unicode display problem in JSF tag

Tags: java, jsf, unicode

I have following line of code for jsp tag

```
<input name="UnicodeVirtualKey" class="btn" type="button" value="&#x0A85;" onclick="insert('&#x0A85;')" />
```

and for JSF

```
<h:commandButton value="&#x0A86" onclick="insert('&#x0A86')" ></h:commandButton>
```

But it will display same i.e `&#x0A86` not its unicode.

shall anybody tell me what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JSF case, you are missing a semicolon in the value attribute. Is that the problem?

---

Actually, given your edit to the question, I think the missing semicolon **probably is** the problem!!

- The character sequence `&0xABCD;` is an XML / HTML character reference for the Unicode codepoint `ABCD`.
- The character sequence `&0xABCD` (missing semicolon!) is just a sequence of characters that stand for themselves.

(If it is not the issue, why did you edit the question to remove the semicolon??)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<f:verbatim>` or `<h:outputText value="&#x0A85;"/>`
Does it print out its unicode? If yes, then you need to figure out how to use it like that.
In facelets/seam, you can use EL expression in javascript